The laptop is not performing too well, but the HDD is finished?
I tried, but it seems that my laptop can't run this version of Ubuntu very well, a downgrade would be needed.
Or, there would be another problem. This is the HDD, one saved from junk, and it also causes problems (maybe). I don't know much about these things, but it's not good when I happen to turn on the laptop and see this on the screen. Power on hours doesn't seem that big to me, but it's still old age, and has 508 reallocated sectors.
It's not very good, is it?
Start-up:

Laptop specs:

HDD status:


With your specs a more lightweight Desktop Environment would be much better. Try Xubuntu or Lubuntu. --> Check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

I would replace the HDD anyways, as it will likely fail and you may loose your data.

Now it is an experiment, both for the OS and for the HDD.

If it's a "run it until it breaks" "experiment", it's broken now. If it's a "torture the system with unreliable hardware" "experiment", shame on you, your test environment is under-instrumented.

I could not use another HDD. I tested two hypotheses, HDD, and the OS on this laptop.
